# Gatsby client side redirects to external URL not working on Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify

I need to do a simple client side redirect to an external URL from a page on my Gatsby site hosted on Netlify. It works fine locally, but nothing seems to work when deployed. There also seems to be a bug with Gatsby's native createRedirect-functionality so that it doesn't allow redirecting to external URLs.

I've tried the three methods below in `componentDidMount`, in `render` as well as in callbacks from a recurring (`setInterval`) function call. I've also tried hijacking clicks on the links that leads to the redirect page and doing `window.open(url)`, but nothing involving `window` seems to be working when deployed.  Any ideas?

```
window.location.replace(url)
window.location.href = url
window.location = url
```

Answer (score 8):

You want to redirect from a url like `/foo` on your site to some external URL like `domain.tld/bar`, is that correct? If so, and you're using Netlify, then you probably want to use the [Netlify `_redirects` file](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/).

However, if you really want to do this inside of Gatsby, you should be able to use the `componentDidMount()` hook to call `window.location.replace()`. I've just tested on our v2 site and this works.

```
class About extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.location.replace("https://www.gatsbycentral.com/");
  }
```

There are some quirks during development, but this should work in production. I tested with a preview branch on Netlify and it worked for me.

If you have a specific error message you could post that as a new question.

Comment: Yes, correct. I tried your code exactly now and it works locally but not when deployed to Netlify, and no error messages. I would use _redirects but I don't know how to programmatically add external links to it, as createRedirect only supports internal links.

Comment: Can you share your public URL? When I tested, this did work on a Netlify preview branch.

Comment: FYI: _redirects is only parsed AFTER building, so if you add lines to it in your build, they'll be used.  You don't need to have it completely built in git.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out to be a bug in Gatsby v2.0.0-beta.15 that broke client side react entirely.