# How to force Gatsby to redirect a specific URL path to an external site?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, redirect

I have a Gatsby site and due to some specific requirements, I need to redirect anyone who attempts to hit a specific URL path, for which there is no page, to an external site. This URL path is not a page within the site, but it's something that a user may be inclined to type due to documentation that is out of my control.

Here's an example: Let's say the site is located at https://www.example.com. A user may visit https://www.example.com/puppies, which does not exist. My file structure does not contain a `src/pages/puppies.js` file. However, when that URL is entered, I need to redirect the user to another site altogether, such as https://www.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Gatsby to that extent to know it has a configuration for this, so someone else may correct me. The way I would handle this is through the hosting provider where your app is.

For example, if you are using Netlify:

Create a `_redirects` file with the following content:

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Or

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

This will cause all `https://yourwebsite.com/IDontHaveThisRoute` to fallback to `/index.html` where your `.js` is loaded.

I provided the Netlify example only to give you the basic idea of how it can be done through the hosting provider of your choice. I would look into configurations I can put into redirects where my domain is deployed.

Comment: We're hosted on AWS. We took over the application from another developer so I'm not entirely familiar with the setup, but I will start looking into it from this perspective. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Netlify currently doesn't support the 307 (Temporary redirect) status code. They suggest sticking with 302 instead. I had trouble figuring out why my redirects with 307 don't work until found their note this in docs: https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Paul Scanlon](https://paulie.dev/) he mentioned using `onRouteUpdate` in [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#onRouteUpdate) and it works like a charm

```
import { navigate } from 'gatsby';


export const onRouteUpdate = ({ location }) => {
  if (location.pathname === '/dashboard') {
    navigate('/dashboard/reports');
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51636607/gatsby-client-side-redirects-to-external-url-not-working-on-netlify) helped point me in the right direction. I was able to get it to work using Gatsby's componentDidMount() to force a redirect as shown below, using a new file called `puppies.js` to "catch" the path typed by the user:

```
// puppies.js

    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    
    class Puppies extends Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            window.location.replace("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
        }
    
        render() {
            return <div />
        }
    }
    
    export default Puppies
```